Counting "lattices" on a circle
It is well-known that the number of lattice points on circle $x^2+y^2=n$ is $4\sum_{d\mid n} \chi_4(d)$,where $\chi_m$ is the non-primitive Dirichlet character $\pmod m$. i.e.
$$
\#\{z\in\mathbb Z[i]: |z|^2=n\}=4\sum_{d\mid n} \chi_4(d)
$$
Let $\omega=\dfrac{-1+\sqrt3}{2}$, then I found that
$$
\#\{z\in\mathbb Z[\omega]: |z|^2=n\}=6\sum_{d\mid n} \chi_3(d)
$$
is true for $n\le 1000$.
I have no idea about proving this conjecture, and any help would be appreciated.

sum of two squares is Theorem 65 on page 80 of  L. E. Dickson (1929), Introduction to the Theory of Numbers.   The similar $n = x^2 + xy + y^2$ is Exercise 2  on that page.

As $\mathbb{Z}[\omega]$ is a Euclidean domain, hence it is a PID and UFD. We can see that the diagram below commutes:
$$
\require{AMScd}
\begin{CD}
    \mathbb{Z}[x]   @>\text{kill }p>>   \mathbb{F}_p[x] \\
 @V\text{kill }x^2+x+1VV       @VV\text{kill }x^2+x+1V \\
    \mathbb{Z}[\omega]   @>>\text{kill }p>   R
\end{CD}$$
We have $$\begin{aligned} &\text{A prime number } p \text{ in } \mathbb{Z} \text{ is a prime in }\mathbb{Z}[\omega]. \\\iff&(p) \text{ is a maximal ideal of }\mathbb{Z}[\omega]. \\\iff& R \text{ is a field}. \\ \iff &(x^2+x+1) \text{ is a maximal ideal in } \mathbb{F}_p[x]. \\ \iff & x^2+x+1 \text{ is irreducible in } \mathbb{F}_p[x] \text{ (as }\mathbb{F}_p[x] \text{ is a PID)}. \\ \iff& p=3k+2 \text{ for a certain integer k (multiplicative group of a finite field is cyclic).} \end{aligned}$$
Decompose $n$ into product of prime numbers: $$n=3^\alpha\times p_1\cdots p_s\times q_1 \cdots q_t\text{,}$$ where $p_i$'s and $q_j$'s are prime numbers in form of $3k+1$ and $3k+2$ respectively, and they need not to be distinct.
Let $T(n)=\#\{z\in\mathbb Z[\omega]: |z|^2=n\}/6,$ one can conjecture that $T(n)$ is a multiplicative function. First, we try to calculate $T(n)$. An easy statement is that $p_i$ can be decomposed into two primes: $$p_i=x_i\bar{x_i},\text{   } x_i \in \mathbb{Z}[\omega].$$
Also:$$3=-\omega^2(1-\omega)^2$$
We can write $n$ as:$$n=(-\omega^2)^\alpha(1-\omega)^{2\alpha}\times x_1\bar{x_1}\cdots x_s\bar{x_s}\times q_1 \cdots q_t\text{.}$$
Since $\mathbb{Z}[\omega]$is a UFD, and there are six units of $\mathbb{Z}[\omega]$:$$\pm 1,\pm \omega, \pm\omega^2, $$if we want $n=z\bar{z}$, then consider $z$'s factorization, the $3k+2$ part also appears in $\bar{z}$'s, that is to say:
$$2\mid v_{q_j}(n).$$
Define a function $N(n)$ as follows:
$$N(n)=\begin{cases} 1,& 2\mid v_{q_j}(n) \text{ for all }j,\\0,& \text{ otherwise. }\end{cases}$$
If $N(n)=0$, then $|z|^2=n$ has no solution, therefore $T(n)=0$. Otherwise $N(n)=1$, one can notice that the $3k+2$ part of $z$ and $\bar{z}$ are the same, so we can simply discard these terms.
To choose $z$, we need to choose a unit $u$ and half of the irreducible components of $n$. (We have discarded the $3k+2$ parts.) If we denote $x_i,\bar{x_i}$ by $x_i^{(1)},x_i^{(2)}$, that is to say:
$$ \{z\in\mathbb Z[\omega]: |z|^2=n\}=\{z:z=u(1-\omega)^{\alpha}\times x_1^{(f_1)}\cdots x_s^{(f_s)}\}=S,$$ since every element is $\mathbb{Z}[\omega]$ can be written as linear combinations of $1$ and $\omega$, and $-\omega^2$ is a unit. It is now clear that $$\#S=6\times 2^s.$$
We now get $$T(n)=2^sN(n),$$ and one can easily check this is a multiplicative function, coincide with the sum $\dfrac{1}{6} \displaystyle\sum_{d\mid n}\chi_3(d).$
Note: One should prove $x_i^{(f_j)}$ does not associate with another $x_i^{(f_j)}$.

L. E. Dickson (1929)  Introduction to the Theory of Numbers.



It is difficult to read pages
